# Arduino based attendance system

Tags: rfid

I am working on a RFID based attendance system. I am using Grove-125 kHz RFID reader, SD card module, DS1307 RTC and Arduino Mega. Each component works alone (separately) with the Arduino well, but whenever I combine them, nothing happens. If I remove the ground or VCC pin of the SD card module, than the code works well. Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h> // for the RFID and SD card module
#include <SD.h> // for the SD card
#include <RTClib.h> // for the RTC
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial RFID(10,11); // RX and TX
#define CS_SD 4 
File myFile;
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
int count=0;
const int buzzer1= 5;
int data1 = 0;
int tag1[14] = {2,48,67,48,48,55,52,51,52,66,66,70,55,3};
int tag2[14] = {2,48,67,48,48,55,52,57,48,48,55,69,70,3};
int tag3[14] = {2,48,67,48,48,55,52,56,65,65,55,53,53,3};
int tag4[14] = {2,48,67,48,48,55,52,51,68,65,70,69,65,3};
int tag5[14] = {2,48,67,48,48,55,52,57,51,69,68,48,54,3}; 
int newtag[14] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // used for read comparisons

void setup()
{
  pinMode(buzzer1, OUTPUT);
  RFID.begin(9600);    // start serial to RFID reader
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial to PC 
  while(!Serial);
  SPI.begin(); 
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if(!SD.begin(CS_SD)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // Setup for the RTC  
  if(!rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while(1);
  }
  else {
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  }
  if(!rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }

}

boolean comparetag(int aa[14], int bb[14])
{
  boolean ff = false;
  int fg = 0;
  for (int cc = 0 ; cc < 14 ; cc++)
  {
    if (aa[cc] == bb[cc])
    {
      fg++;
    }
  }
  if (fg == 14)
  {
    ff = true;
  }
  return ff;
}

void checkmytags() // compares each tag against the tag just read
{
  if (comparetag(newtag, tag1) == true)
  {
  count=1; 
     Serial.print(count);
   Serial.println("Amimul");
  }
  else if (comparetag(newtag, tag2) == true)
  {
  count=2;
     Serial.print(count);
   Serial.println("Amimul");
  }
   else if (comparetag(newtag, tag3) == true)
  {
   count=3;
      Serial.print(count);
   Serial.println("Amimul");
      Serial.print(count);
   Serial.println("Amimul");
  }
   else if (comparetag(newtag, tag4) == true)
  {
   count=4;
   Serial.print(count);
   Serial.println("Amimul");
  }
   else if (comparetag(newtag, tag5) == true)
  {
   count=5;
      Serial.print(count);
   Serial.println("Amimul");
  }
}

void readTags()
{
  if (RFID.available() > 0) 
  {
    delay(100); // needed to allow time for the data to come in from the serial buffer.
    for (int z = 0 ; z < 14 ; z++) // read the rest of the tag
    {
      data1 = RFID.read();
      newtag[z] = data1;
    }
    RFID.flush(); // stops multiple reads
    tone(buzzer1,4000); 
    delay(300);        
    noTone(buzzer1);
    checkmytags();
  } 
}
void logCard(){
     digitalWrite(CS_SD,LOW);
    myFile=SD.open("Sir.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    if(myFile){
      if(count=="1"){
        myFile.print("Ridwanul basit,1\n");
        Serial.println("Ridwanul basit");
      }
        if(count=="2"){
        myFile.print("Afik Arman,2\n");
        Serial.println("Afik Arman");
        }
        if(count=="3"){
        myFile.print("Afnaf Tahmid,3\n");
        Serial.println("Afnaf Tahmid");
        }
        if(count=="4"){
        myFile.print("Al Mahmud,6\n");
        Serial.println("Al Mahmud");
        }
       if(count=="5"){
        myFile.print("Fahim Muntasir,11\n");
        Serial.println("Fahim Muntasir");
      }
    myFile.print(", ");
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    myFile.print(now.year(), DEC);
    myFile.print('/');
    myFile.print(now.month(), DEC);
    myFile.print('/');
    myFile.print(now.day(), DEC);
    myFile.print(',');
    myFile.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    myFile.print(':');
    myFile.println(now.minute(), DEC);
    myFile.close();
    }
    digitalWrite(CS_SD,LOW);
    delay(100);
}
void loop()
{
  readTags();
  logCard();
  delay(10);
}
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Does the initializing code send the correct messages, marking that the initialization was successfull? You should see some serial output, if the sketch is running. Please copy&paste the serial output to your question.

Comment: why do you use SoftwareSerial on Mega with 4 hardware serials?

Comment: what did you try to debug the problem? some debug prints? removing one of the components?

Comment: Yes.It initializes the sd card.And then nothing happens.@chrisl

Comment: Because I have to change the code multiple time.So,if i use hardware serial,i will have to remove Tx and Rx pin again and again.@Juraj

Comment: The Serial output is only this line:"Initializing Sd card..........Initialization done"

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy&Paste the text directly into the question an format it with the `{}` button as code. (Is easier to read then)

Comment: Get's something written into the file on the SD card?

Comment: And please show us your wiring (schematics or wiring diagram)

Comment: @amimulahsan Only Serial (pins 0/1) are affected by uploading the sketch. The other three serial ports are completely independent. You should be using those, not SoftwareSerial. SoftwareSerial is a last resort.

Comment: `RFID.flush(); // stops multiple reads` -- No it doesn't. It blocks until all pending writes have completed. Flush changed in operation with Arduino 1.0.0.

Comment: Yes.Only an empty text file is written.@chrisl

Comment: So what should i do@Majenko

Comment: can anyone please give me a better coding idea to make a 125hz rfid reader based attendence system?

Comment: @amimulahsan What should you do with what? The flush? Just delete it, it's pointless. The `SoftwareSerial`? Use TX1/RX1 pins and the `Serial1` object. Or TX2/RX2 and `Serial2`. Or TX3/RX3 and `Serial3`.

Comment: I just deleted it.But the result are still the same@Majenko